# Show syntax name for code snippets

Tags: syntax-highlighting, jekyll, kramdown, coderay

I'm using Jekyll with Kramdown and Coderay.

Is there a way to add the name of the syntax rules used to the output of the code highlighter, when using kramdown? I'd like it to look similar to what [ajax-syntax-highlighter](http://dunglas.fr/wp-content/plugins/ajax-syntax-highlighter/test.html) outputs. Thus showing the syntax name above the actual code.

Also, being able to add comments to the code snippets would be nice. Just like [Octopress](http://octopress.org/docs/blogging/code/) does.

Are there any plugins for this, maybe?
And no, I do not want to switch to using Octopress instead :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight code like octopress, use [include_code plugin](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/blob/master/plugins/include_code.rb).

The simplest way is to use **figure** tag.

```
<figure>
  {% highlight ruby %}
  def print_hi(name)
    puts "Hi, #{name}"
  end
  {% endhighlight %}
  <figcaption>
    <cite>ruby code</cite>
    any additional comment here ...
  </figcaption>

</figure>
```